# Overriding new sub form's event

Tags: c#, winforms, overriding

According to my knowledge, event methods are protected and can be override and used only within derived classes.

So, having the following `Form` defined in the `main Form`:

```
Form ModelBuilderSAS = new Form()
{
    //Stuff..
};
```

Is it somehow possible to override its `OnPaint` inside the operating method or at least in the same class?

This is my current solution:

```
public partial class ModelBuilder : Form
{
    public partial class ModelBuilderSAS : Form
    {
        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            //Do Stuff Before OnPaint..
            base.OnPaint(e);
        }
    }
}
```

But it's not so practical since there are at least 10 sub-forms in each of my primary forms.

Addition: The reason for overriding the OnPaint instead of just handling the event is that i want to perform some actions first then continue with the `OnPaint`

Comment: Why have you nested one form within another? That looks like a bad idea to me. And do you really need to override the method rather than just handling the event?

Comment: I couldn't think of a better solution, and yes it is preferred to override it although i could normally handle it but it won't give the desired result i need.

Comment: Well what result do you need? You haven't explained what you're trying to achieve, which makes it really hard to help you - nor have you explained *why* you think you need a nested type at all.

Comment: I need to perform something before the actual `OnPaint` goes on.

Comment: So please explain that in the question. If you need to take the same action in all cases, it sounds like you could just create an abstract base class deriving from `Form`, and then make your "subforms" derive from that.

Comment: I don't know how i couldn't think of that but thank you for the help and apologies for the unclarity.